# Symfony cascade persist or merge duplication

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with the cascade persist or merge, I have an application with two entities task and table (task_implements)

When I create a task I choose cultures that are linked:

- If the user chooses 3 cultures => 3 tasks are created
- If the user chooses 3 cultures then 2 vehicles => 3 tasks must be
  created and each task 2 vehicles bind

TaskController new()

```
if ( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        // Cultures
        foreach ( $form->get('cultures')->getData() as $culture) {
            // Set correct status
            if ( $task->getUser() === null ) {
                $task->setStatus( 2 );
            } else {
                $task->setStatus( 3 );
            }
            $task->setCulture( $culture );

            // Implements

            foreach ( $form->get('implements')->getData() as $implement) {
                $taskImplement = new TaskImplement();
                $taskImplement->setImplement( $implement );

                $task->addImplement( $taskImplement );
            }

            $this->em->merge( $task );
            $this->em->flush();
        }


        $this->addFlash('success', 'Nouvelle tache ajoutée avec succès');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_task_index');
    }
```

TaskNewType

```
->add('implements', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Implement::class,
            'query_builder' => function( ImplementRepository $ir ) {
                return $ir->createQueryBuilder('i');
            },
            'choice_label' => function( Implement $implement ) {
                return $implement->getName();
            },
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ])
```

TaskEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TaskImplement::class, mappedBy="task", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 */
private $implements;

public function addImplement(TaskImplement $taskImplement): self
{
    if (!$this->implements->contains($taskImplement)) {
        $this->implements[] = $taskImplement;
        $taskImplement->setTask($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**Desired behavior**

If I take example, if I choose 3 cultures application creates 3 tasks and in every task create 2 implement bind

```
id / culture_id
#1 10
#2 11
#3 12
```

in task_implement

```
 id / task_id / implement_id
 #1 1 20
 #2 1 21
 #3 2 20
 #4 2 21
 #5 3 20
 #6 3 21
```

**What I get**

```
     id / culture_id
     #1 10
     #2 11
     #3 12
```

on task_implement

```
     id / task_id / implement_id

     #1 | 1 | 20 @
     #2 | 1 | 21 

     #3 | 2 | 20 @
     #4 | 2 | 21 @
     #5 | 2 | 20 @
     #6 | 2 | 21 

     #7 | 3 | 20 @
     #8 | 3 | 21 @
     #9 | 3 | 20 @
     #10 | 3 | 21 @
     #11 | 3 | 20 @
     #12 | 3 | 21
```

I don't understand why it doesn't clear between each record in DB and it duplicates if I put 4 cultures I have 4 entries on the last TaskImplement

Thank you for your help

Comment: Show us your entities

Comment: @AndreyMashukov Task or TaskImplement ?

Comment: both entities please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `merge` creates a new task entry every time you call it (this probably means, that your `$task` doesn't have an id.

On the first cycle of your outer `foreach` you add 2 TaskImplements, which also don't have ids. Your task now have 2 TaskImplements (which is what you want at this point).

On the second cycle of your outer `foreach` you add *another* 2 TaskImplements - now you have 4 TaskImplements on your task.

Solution options:

- you either need to stop adding TaskImplements after the first outer foreach (which would be weird, but would work) or
- you **set** your task implements instead of adding them or
- clear the task object of task implements before adding new ones or
- you "clone" the task before adding task implements (it might be sufficient to just create a new task?).

#### afterthought

You got a very interesting use of `merge`. With persist, you should only would have had *one* Task that contains 6 TaskImplement and only has the last culture set. To be honest, merge without having ids on the task feels like an anti-pattern.

I would assume, that your form itself has data_type Task, which is essentially wrong, since you're editing/creating multiple tasks. You handle the form as if you have multiple tasks, but you only have one. The root of your problem stems from the wrong semantics ...

Comment: Thx for your reply @Jakumi  so if I understood correctly I must create a new form without data_class ? 

What is the correct sementics ?

Comment: the data_class of one form describes the data, that is produced by that form / the form manages. if the data_class is Task, it means the form is meant to create one task / edit one task. if you remove the data_class the semantics is, that you create an array. you could then create tasks all over the place and add to it whatever you like, that would have been my approach. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

it's ok i managed to do it this my controller code on submit

```
if ( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        // Cultures
        foreach ( $form->get('cultures')->getData() as $culture) {
            // Set correct status
            if ( $task->getUser() === null ) {
                $task->setStatus( 2 );
            } else {
                $task->setStatus( 3 );
            }
            $task->setCulture( $culture );

            $this->em->persist( $task );

            // Implements

            foreach ( $form->get('implements')->getData() as $implement) {
                $taskImplement = new TaskImplement();
                $taskImplement->setImplement( $implement );
                $taskImplement->setTask( $task );

                $this->em->persist( $taskImplement );
            }

            $this->em->flush();

            $this->em->clear( Task::class );
            $this->em->clear( TaskImplement::class );
        }



        $this->addFlash('success', 'Nouvelle tache ajoutée avec succès');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_task_index');
    }
```

I just clear two entity on every each

And is work